# allocating memory to an array of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management

I would like to fill an array of strings using two functions: the first, if I have n strings to allocate, will allocate n memory spaces; the second will allocate memory for each string read

Here is the first function:

```
char** allocate(int n)
{
    char** t;
    t=(char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    if(!t) exit(-1);
    return t;
}
```

Here is the second one:

```
void fill(char*** t,int n)
    {
        int i;
        char* help=" ";
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n saisir la chaine n %d :",i+1);
                scanf("%s",help);
                *t[i]=(char*)malloc((strlen(help)+1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(*t[i],help);
        }
    }
```

I did not forget to call the second one in `main` like this : `fill(&t,n);`

The problem is that I get an error after reading the first string and program ends.

Comment: This is not going to work `char* help=" ";`

Comment: To expand on that: when you call `scanf("%s", help)` then `help` must point to a memory location large enough to hold the string that is being read in.

Comment: You do not need to cast the results of `malloc` in C.

Comment: @qwrrty These comments are perfectly useful.

Comment: @qwrrty Um, no. Firstly because it's not a distraction but a piece of good advice, secondly because it's not silly.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's a fine piece of advice to give, but it is demonstrably not going to solve the poster's problem, which is why it is a distraction in this context. Posting "you must define a buffer properly so that you can read into it, and by the way, it's a bad idea to cast the results of malloc" would be helpful. This isn't.

Comment: Is someone deleting my comments? Now that's just tacky.

Comment: @qwrrty You seem to be ignoring the fact that Dasblinkenlight didn't post his advice as an answer, but only as a comment.

Comment: Many problems, especially straightforward ones like this, are solved in the comments. And many others are sent off the rails with well meaning but misleading comments like these. I say again: making a suggestion like "don't cast the return call from malloc" is a fine suggestion to make, but not if it implies that it is the cause of the poster's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not allocate the memory for help variable.

Change `char* help=" ";` to `char help[512]="";`

this way help points to a string literal (constant stored in memory block, which is not allowed to be changed.

Comment: @user3104033: Be aware that entering more then 511 characters will make the program fail again miserably, as the allocated memory will be overwritten and undefined behaviour will arise,

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
char* help=" ";
```

just defines a pointer pointing to `" "`.

There is no memory allocated to then store the data to be scanned in via `scanf()`.

If you have a maximum of character to be scanned in do it as follows:

```
#define SCAN_MAXIMUM (255)
#define SCAN_FMT_STRINGIFY(max) "%"#max"s"
#define SCAN_FMT(max) SCAN_FMT_STRINGIFY(max)

...

  char help[SCAN_MAXIMUM + 1]; /* Add one for the road^H^H^H^H`0`-terminator. */
  scanf(SCAN_FMT(SCAN_MAXIMUM), help);
```

---

Also these lines do not what you want:

```
    *t[i]=(char*)malloc((strlen(help)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*t[i],help);
```

The `[]` operator binds tighter then the `*` operator, so the lines should look like

```
    (*t)[i] = malloc((strlen(help) + 1));
    strcpy((*t)[i], help);
```

---

Also^2: There is no need in C to cast the results of `malloc/calloc/realloc`, nor is it recommnended.

---

Also^3: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be equal `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`fill()`  should just take `char * *`, I think you're getting a operator precedence problem.

Since you don't need to re-allocate the array inside `fill()`, there's no point to have three levels of indirection. You should change it to just two, and of course call without the `&`.

Comment: As you told me, I took char** and I changed char* help=" "; to char aide[]=" ";
Now the programs asks me for all the strings, but the problem now occures after writing the last string with this error : "Stack around the variable 'aide' was corrupted"

Comment: If `t` is declared `char **t` and he passes the address of this variable as `fill (&t, n)` then the declaration `char ***t` was quite correct. I agree that there appears to be no need for the additional level of indirection in the code that has been posted here, though, and if `t` does not get re-allocated then it makes sense to remove unnecessary levels of redirection.