# #define string with numeric define

Tags: c, constants, c-preprocessor

For example, here is a **C** common `#define`:

```
#define USERNAME_LEN  100
#define SCAN_FMT  "%100s"

// str is input from somewhere
char username[USERNAME_LEN + 1];
ret = sscanf(str, SCAN_FMT, username);
// check ret == 1 ?
```

can we have something like:

```
#define SCAN_FMT   "%" USERNAME_LEN "s"
```

of course, this syntax is not what we want, but the ultimate goal
is to mix numeric #define into string #define

Note: I know we can do something like:

```
sprintf(SCAN_FMT, "%%ds", USERNAME_LEN); // char SCAN_FMT[10];
```

but this is not what I am looking for, because it requires run-time generation,
the best is to base on ANSI-C or std99.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20642870/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to do it like this:

```
#define SCAN_FMT_STRINGIFY(max) "%"#max"s"
#define SCAN_FMT(max) SCAN_FMT_STRINGIFY(max)

#define USERNAME_MAXLEN (100)

...

  char username[USERNAME_MAXLEN + 1] = ""; /* Add one for the `0`-terminator. */
  int ret = sscanf(str, SCAN_FMT(USERNAME_MAXLEN), username);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the preprocessor directives for these kind of tasks.

1.The first directive is # allows you to do such things:

```
#define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
```

This will be translated into:

```
cout << "test";
```

2.The second directive is ##:

```
#define glue(a,b) a ## b
glue(c,out) << "test";
```

will be translated into:

```
cout << "test";
```

Look here for more info [preprocessor](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Comment: There is a piece missing. OP wants to stringize a defined value **after it has been substuted**. IIRC, doing so requires a third `#define`.

Comment: Not that it matters much for your answer, but the question is tagged C and no C++.